# Facebook Integration with an external site

Tags: api, facebook, integration

Hii..
I am working on developing a website and I want it to be integrated with Facebook, i.e. I want to fetch logged-in user's information like his wall info, comments, his feeds etc. along with his friends's information,their comments etc..
Also I want user of my website to be able to post comments, feeds on his wall, update / upload picture etc.
And all that I want to do using facebook API..
Is there any way to do it..? Please help me out, I am really not getting the way that how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

Yes this all possible, but your question is too vague to have definite answer.

First you need to learn about:

- [Social plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/plugins)
- [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
- [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (see Single Sign-on with the JavaScript SDK)
- [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

If after that you still have some specific questions we would be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what languages/technology stacks you may be considering for your site, but you could also check for plugins that interface w/ the fb API such as

[Facebooker](http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/) - Rails plugin

[Facebook Graph Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/facebook-graph) - Grails plugin